# select2 and bootstrap text field not align in rails form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, jquery-select2

As you can see in the image below, the text field (using bootstrap) is not align horizontally with select2 dropdown listbox. How can I make it align ?

[image: not align input]

The following is the _form.html.erb code snippet. 
The complete code can be found here https://gist.github.com/axilaris/9597320

there 2 are the inputs that are not aligned <%= f.text_field :name %> and <%= select_tag(:option,..

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('select#option').select2();
    });

</script>
 <br><br>
 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :name %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
 <%= select_tag(:option, 
    options_for_select([['All', 1], ['Co', 2], ['Bought', 3]] )) %>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use select2 and Bootstrap in few projects. Select2 got its own style and applies after bootstrap. I think you'll have to play with some css margin, padding etc. You can give specific class to your select_tag for a better targeting:

```
<%= select_tag(:option, options_for_select([['All', 1], ['Co', 2], ['Bought', 3]] ), {class: "my-specific-class-for-select2"}) %>
```

[documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag)

EDIT: with data-live-search

```
<%= select_tag(:option, options_for_select([['All', 1], ['Co', 2], ['Bought', 3]] ), {class: "my-specific-class-for-select2", data:{live_search: "true"}) %>
```

The tag will get the data-live-search attribute. Note that the underscore (_) will become an -.

[Documentation about the tags and data attributes.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag)

EDIT2:

With some adjustments in the html and css I got this working:

```
application.scss

/*Solution for bootsrap styling compliance*/
a.select2-choice{
  height: 35px !important;
  span{
   padding-top: 4px;
  }
}



In the view

<div class="form-group clearfix">
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><%= f.text_field :title,  {class: "form-control"} %></div>
  <div class="col-sm-3"><%= select_tag(:type,
  options_for_select([['All', 1], ['Co', 2], ['Bought', 3], ['View', 4], ['Top API', 5]] ), {style: "width:100%;"}) %></div>
</div>


<div class="actions clearfix">
  <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: if that is the case, is there a way to do data-live-search="true" in rails ? atleast it has similar functionality with select2 and probably then it will be aligned. its probably better not to touch or add in additional css. i dont want to complicate things for this example. thanks. found this link http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: i tried something like this it didnt work <%= select_tag(:option, options_for_select([['All', 1], ['Co', 2], ['Bought', 3], ['View', 4], ['Top API', 5]] ), {"class" => "selectpicker", "data-live-search" =>"true"} ) %>

Comment: You can use the unobtrusive javascript method and pass the data attribute with a hash here is the doc and i'm updating my answer. Doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag

Comment: I'm looking into the link you give, it looks like that you can use this to replace select2. I'll give it a try for simple select_tag.

Comment: i tried adding bootstrap-select.js and bootstrap-select.css into vendor/assets/javascript and stylesheet folder. and added application.js and application.css to require bootstrap-select. just copying and paste the example code didnt help. it should be enabled once the script initialize this. $('select').selectpicker();   --- maybe you can show me how an example you have done to align bootstrap and select2, how did you add extra style into your code ?

Comment: Did you check to see if the js files where loading with your page? According to this exemple http://jsfiddle.net/ericstob/52VtD/181/ you also need to add a data-container="body" to get this working. In my apps i used select2 because of the ajax remote possibility, if the design is messing i just add few custom css rules to adjust the styling. I'll try to build an app with your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49886/discussion-between-coding-addicted-and-axil)